# Angular 2 form validation with custom validators ng-valid class

Tags: css, forms, angular

I'm trying to build a form with custom validations, here is an example:

```
this.registrationForm= fb.group({
  dob: ['', Validators.required],
  email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required,  emailValidator])],
  password: ['', Validators.required],
  confirmPassword: ['', Validators.required],
  firstName: ['', Validators.required],
  lastName: ['', Validators.required]
}, {validator: matchingPasswords('password', 'confirmPassword')})
```

i have only one problem - the ng-invalid css class from the NgModel directive won't fire for the custom validator, anyone encountered with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the CSS file the 'ng-invalid' class associated with [required] so it won't fire without it and the custom Validator is not 'required'. 
for example:

```
<input required type=”text” ngControl=”username” />
```